# Datetimepicker maxDate not working

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I am using jquery datetimepicker and trying to set the max date to be May 7th, for some reason, no matter what I put for the maxDate param, it always limits the maxDate to today (5-May-2016). Am I doing something wrong ?

Which then gives me the correct value, but the max date is always set to today and not 7-May-2016.

Code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#AuditDate').datetimepicker({timepicker: false,format:'d-M-Y', maxDate: '07-May-2016', value: '05-May-2016'});                                   
});
```

Comment: check this [ js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ramachandra/2y67W/285/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try format below to match your maxDate format:

```
format:'dd-M-yy'
```

Comment: I changed the format to format:'d-M-Y' and it worked. Thankyou so much!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `datetimepicker` range dates (minDate and maxDate) is that they HAVE TO have a correct format (e.g.`Y/M/d`, `Y/m/d`, `d-M-Y`) but this doesn't mean that your js object have to! Below I added full working code.
ps. I'm using `momentjs` library so you have to add it to your code ;)

Html:

```
<input id="date_from" type="text" >
<input id="date_to" type="text" >
```

Js:

```
(function($) {
"use strict";

var dtpFrom = $("input[name=date_from]");
var dtpTo = $("input[name=date_to]");

dtpFrom.datetimepicker({
    lang: 'pl',
    format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
    closeOnDateSelect: true,
    onShow:function( ct ) {
        var setMaxDate = moment(dtpTo.val()).format('YYYY/MM/DD');

        this.setOptions({
            maxDate: setMaxDate
                    ? setMaxDate
                    : false
        })
    },
    timepicker:false
});

dtpTo.datetimepicker({
    lang: 'pl',
    format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
    closeOnDateSelect: true,
    onShow:function( ct ){
        var setMinDate = moment(dtpFrom.val()).format('YYYY/MM/DD');

        this.setOptions({
            minDate: setMinDate
                    ? setMinDate
                    : false
        })
    },
    timepicker:false
});
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $('.some_class').datetimepicker({
        timepicker: false,
        format:'d-M-Y',
        maxDate : '2016/05/25'
    });
</script>
// Just pass the max date in this format.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// replase maxDate to endDate     
$(".datepicker_ate_hoje").datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    weekStart: 1,
    todayBtn: "linked",
    endDate: new Date(),
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
});
```

Comment: Rather than simply writing code, it is better to also provide an explanation of how this solves the original problem.